# Aggregate a Dask dataframe and produce a dataframe of aggregates

Tags: group-by, aggregation, dask

I have a Dask dataframe that looks like this:

```
url     referrer    session_id ts                  customer
url1    ref1        xxx        2017-09-15 00:00:00 a.com
url2    ref2        yyy        2017-09-15 00:00:00 a.com
url2    ref3        yyy        2017-09-15 00:00:00 a.com
url1    ref1        xxx        2017-09-15 01:00:00 a.com
url2    ref2        yyy        2017-09-15 01:00:00 a.com
```

I want to group the data on url and timestamp, aggregate column values and produce a dataframe that would look like this instead:

```
customer url    ts                  page_views visitors referrers
a.com    url1   2017-09-15 00:00:00 1          1        [ref1]
a.com    url2   2017-09-15 00:00:00 2          2        [ref2, ref3]
```

In Spark SQL, I can do this as follows:

```
select 
    customer,
    url,
    ts,
    count(*) as page_views,
    count(distinct(session_id)) as visitors,
    collect_list(referrer) as referrers
from df
group by customer, url, ts
```

Is there any way I can do it with Dask dataframes? I tried, but I can only calculate the aggregated columns separately, as follows:

```
# group on timestamp (rounded) and url
grouped = df.groupby(['ts', 'url'])

# calculate page views (count rows in each group)
page_views = grouped.size()

# collect a list of referrer strings per group
referrers = grouped['referrer'].apply(list, meta=('referrers', 'f8'))

# count unique visitors (session ids)
visitors = grouped['session_id'].count()
```

But I can't seem to find a good way to produce a combined dataframe that I need.

Comment: Is there a nice way to do this in Pandas?  Does that way work for dask.dataframe?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following does indeed work:

```
gb = df.groupby(['customer', 'url', 'ts'])
gb.apply(lambda d: pd.DataFrame({'views': len(d), 
     'visitiors': d.session_id.count(), 
     'referrers': [d.referer.tolist()]})).reset_index()
```

(assuming visitors should be unique as per the sql above)
You may wish to define the `meta` of the output.

Comment: Nice! Will it force all the data into the memory on one machine, if I construct a `pd.DataFrame` out of my data? Right now it's a toy example, but the real job would work with gigabytes of distributed data.

Comment: It seemed to work with data exactly like yours; you should try providing a meta parameter http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/dataframe-api.html#dask.dataframe.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.apply

Comment: You're right, it worked with data exactly as I specified it in this example.
It didn't work on a slightly bigger example of data read from partitioned parquet. I would like to figure out what exactly is wrong with that one - I'll file an issue in dask with my data sample. Stackoverflow does not look like a good place for that. Thank you!

Comment: How do you provide a correct `meta` in this example? I tried with `meta = {'views': int, 'visitors': int, 'referrers': object}`, but that didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

This is the [link to the github issue](https://github.com/dask/dask/issues/2706) that @j-bennet opened that gives an additional option. Based on the issue we implemented the aggregation as follows:
`custom_agg = dd.Aggregation(
    'custom_agg', 
    lambda s: s.apply(set), 
    lambda s: s.apply(lambda chunks: list(set(itertools.chain.from_iterable(chunks)))),
)`.
In order to combine with the count the code is as follows
`dfgp = df.groupby(['ID1','ID2'])
df2 = dfgp.assign(cnt=dfgp.size()).agg(custom_agg).reset_index()`