# pandas groupby performance

Tags: pandas, numpy, pandas-groupby, dask

I'm running on a workstation with lots of ram (190GB).
we need to `groupby` on a datasets with millions of records [ normally with 2 ID columns, 1 type ID column, 1 date column and 3-5 categorical columns] (between 10-30 M), while generating a list of the aggregated columns.
Our problem is that the performance is VERY slow. running the same code in `R` runs in less then an hour.

The current test dataset is **only 7.7Million records**.  The data looks like this:

```
ID1         ID2         typeid    date_      cat1    cat2   cat3
12554876563 1435465465  09238423  2013-04-2  cat11   cat21  cat31
12554876563 1435465465  984375    2012-11-12 cat12   cat21  cat33
125543213   12554876563 01248423  2012-04-2  cat11   cat23  cat31
5436236563  125543213   09275423  2017-04-2  cat13   cat24  cat32
```

The `groupby` looks as follows:

```
def agg_col(var):
    li = ';'.join([str(i) for i in set(var.dropna())])
    return li

    df = ( df.groupby(['ID1','ID2']).agg(lambda x: agg_col(x))
             .assign(weight=df.groupby(['ID1','ID2']).size())
```

We also tried using [dask as suggested in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46375382/aggregate-a-dask-dataframe-and-produce-a-dataframe-of-aggregates/46380632) but still we are having problems, the `aggregate-agg` processes takes over an hour.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you profiled? I would assume the `str` in the comprehension is taking all the time.

Comment: What options do I have if I need to generate a list with a `;` delimiter? Maybe to vectorize the `str` on all columns before running the `groupby`

Comment: Can you add a portion of your data to this question?  Maybe 4 or five rows from a few different groups.

Comment: I've added a sample

Comment: Perhaps https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.join.html can help? I would wonder *why* you want such a representation.

Comment: The data is loaded later on into [neo4j](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/3.3/tools/import/file-header-format/). if the ';' delimiter is a problem we can use the `--array-delimiter`. but we still need to concatenate the values into a list.

Comment: the issue is: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/17594 there is a soln in the end of the issue (use codes as the grouper); will be fixed in upcoming 0.23.0

Answer (score 1):

Changing the 'category' Series to 'int' did improve the performance but still was not good enough.
Our solution was to dump it into sqlite -> groupby -> and reload.
The below dataset completed after less then 5 min.

```
con = sqlite3.connect('/path/to/tempdb.db')
df.to_sql('data', con, if_exists='replace')
sql_index = 'create index id12_idx on data(ID1, ID2)'
con.execute(sql_index)
sql_gp = 'SELECT ID1, ID2, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT typeid), GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT date_), GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT cat1), GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT cat2), GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT cat3) from data GROUP BY ID1, ID2')
df = pd.read_sql_query(sql_gp, con)
```

Comment: BTW we tried to implement [this issue using the  Dask framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55107708/how-to-improve-function-using-pd-groupby-transform-in-a-dask-environment?noredirect=1#comment97193397_55107708) with limited success.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this:

I think you are doing two groupby's when I suspect you can get away with one by using a list in your `agg` method.   Also, I think we a get rid of that list comprehension and use `unique` with `join`.

```
df.groupby(['ID1','ID2']).agg([lambda x: ';'.join(x.dropna().unique()),'size'])
```

and you can rename your columns afterwards using `.rename(columns={'<lambda>':'agg_col','size':'weight'})`

Comment: The argument to `agg` can be a dict mapping column names to functions, right?

Comment: @mdurant that dictionary rename was remove a few version back.  I think in 0.19 or so.

Comment: Oh, unfortunate. Seems like a nice compact way to phrase the procedure.

Comment: BTW - I tried the above code and it is already running for over an hour.

Comment: @JosephBerry Okay....  Maybe we need to look at using per numpy.  You should edit this question with numpy as a tag.